# Can not see name of objects or prefixes in my generated lang.TRIG or lang.NQUADS file

Tags: java, rdf, jena, shacl

I have a datatset and I create a ttl file after any changement of my dataset.
The output of my file after using is something like :

RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, dataset, Lang.TRIG);

```
<http://tge.test.com/pro>
        <http://tge.test.com/creator>
                "Alice" ;
       <http://tge.test.com/date>  "08.07.2022 16:07:24" ;
       <http://tge.test.com/projectName>
                "project15" .

<http://tge.test.com/project2>
       <http://tge.test.com/creator>
                "MyName" ;
        <http://tge.test.com/date>  "09.07.2022 10:24:03" ;
        <http://tge.test.com/projectName>
                "project2" .
```

**I would like that my ttl file would like something like this :**

```
@prefix ex: <http://tge.test.com/> .
ex:project15
    a ex:Project;
    ex:projectName "project15";
    ex:date "08.07.2022 16:07:24";
    ex:creator "Alice" .


ex:project2
    a ex:Project;
    ex:projectName "project2";
    ex:date "09.07.2022 10:24:03";
    ex:creator "MyName" .
```

**I want to see every type of object : project for example.**
And my intention is to validate this file using shacl, I guess without specifing the type of my object I can not validate its with shacl.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Kindly mark  the solution as the answer if it helps/works for you. Thanks!

Comment: I want to see every type of object : project for example. And my intention is to validate this file using shacl, I guess without specifing the type of my object I can not validate its with shacl. Did you got the its ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume `dataset` is a `Model` object. You can use the `setNsPrefixes(String prefix, String URI)` on your `Model` object as shown below.

```
dataset.setNsPrefix("ex", "http://tge.test.com/" )
```

Running `RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, dataset, Lang.TRIG);` then should fetch your expected results. As for shacl validation,

```
import org.apache.jena.shacl.Shapes;
import org.apache.jena.shacl.ValidationReport;
import org.apache.jena.shacl.lib.ShLib;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Graph;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr;

Graph shapesGraph = RDFDataMgr.loadGraph("shapes/file/path"); //load your shapes graph
Shapes shapes = Shapes.parse(shapesGraph); //parse it to a Shapes object


Graph dataGraph = dataset.getGraph(); 
ValidationReport report = ShaclValidator.get().validate(shapes, dataGraph); // do the validation

//print reports
ShLib.printReport(report); 
System.out.println();
RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, report.getModel(), Lang.TTL);
```

### EDIT 1: Example SHACL Shape

```
@prefix sh:<http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#>.
@prefix ex:<http://tge.test.com/>.

ex:MyShape 
    a sh:NodeShape;
    # target instances(objects) of class ex:Project
    sh:targetClass ex:Project;
    # an example property shape to validate that each project must have a
    # creator, or rather an object along the predicate ex:creator
    sh:property [
        a sh:PropertyShape;
        sh:path ex:creator;
        sh:minCount 1;
        ] .
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, what still I did not got is how to add my the type of every object in the output of this command :

RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, dataset, Lang.TRIG);

I want to see every type of object : project for example. And my intention is to validate this file using shacl, I guess without specifing the type of my object I can not validate its with shacl.

Comment: There are a few things I don't understand. What do you mean by you what to "see" every type of object: project. If all you want is get all the projects that are instances (*is object of*) class `ex:Project` all you need is a simple SPARQL Query or read the graph programmatically.

However if you are looking to validate all instances of `ex:Project`, say as an example if there exists some property on them, then you need SHACL as you rightly mentioned. You would need to have  Node Shape that has a Class-based target of your `ex:Project` class. Please check edited answer for an example.

Comment: I want to see the type of every object in my ttl file. I guess I missed to specify  rdf:type at the time of creation of my dataset.

Comment: that seems to be true, btw the token `a` in the predicate position in turtle format (.ttl) represents `rdf:type`, so `ex:project15 a ex:Project` and `ex:project15 rdf:type ex:Project` are the same